# HTML for playing .MOV files in Safari 8 -- What Changed?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, quicktime, .mov

I have a fairly large library of **QuickTime .MOV** files that get served by a page that used to work great; **the HTML hasn't changed in years**, but someone noticed it no longer works in Safari, although all other browsers seem to be fine.

Instead, now in **Safari 8.0.7 in OS X**, it shows a "**Missing Plug-In**" button, which when pressed pops up an alert that says:

> This web page has content that requires an Internet plug-in.
>
> This page contains content that cannot be shown because its type is unspecified.
>   This page may have the plug-in for you to download and install:
>
> http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/
>
> Want to open this page?

Pressing OK takes me there, but all I get with OS X is "QuickTime is built into Mac OS X."  No plug-in.

While I'd like nothing better than to switch to .MP4 format and use the HTML5 [VIDEO](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) tag, **I'm trying to maintain backwards compatibility**.  Besides the new video tag can only play MP4, WebM, and Ogg formats. It seems absurd that Apple can't play QuickTime files in its own browser. [see UPDATE below]

Except that... it can. **Loading the direct URL to the .MOV file plays perfectly**, suggesting it's not so much the format, but **the HTML that's at fault**.  In fact, I see QuickTime 7.7.3 listed in the [plug-in list](http://file:///Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Plug-ins.html).

What's being *generated* is:

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="320" height="256" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab#version=7,3,0,0" align="middle">
  <param name="src" value="file.mov">
  <param name="kioskmode" value="true">
  <embed src="file.mov" width="320" height="256" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" align="middle" kioskmode="true">
</object>
```

I say 'generated' because I'm following Apple's [HTML Scripting](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001525-2-HTMLScripting) guidelines, which say to use [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/samplecode/HTML_video_example/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007723-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)'s `ac_quicktime.js` script (v1.2), written *by Apple*, to generate the correct code for the given browser.

```
<script language="javacript" type="text/javascript">
  QT_WriteOBJECT('file.mov', 
    '320', '256', 
    '',
    'kioskmode', 'true',
    'pluginspage','http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/',
    'align', 'middle'); 
</script>
```

Inspecting the DOM with Safari's Web Inspector shows the JavaScript above does indeed generate the object/embed block.

I've even validated with `wget` that the MIME type is correct when pulling the media file directly:

```
Content-Type: video/quicktime
```

A little experimentation using Ghostery and uBlock Origin show nothing is being blocked. Being in control of the site, it confirms there are no trackers, and as it generates the above content, it isn't blocking JavaScript.

More experimentation shows this problem happens on my iPhone and iPad as well. No "Missing Plug-In" button, just a empty hole on the canvas where the movie should be.

[ffprobe](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) reports a valid video file (H.264, 320x240; AAC 48000 Hz, Mono, 29.97 fps, 19.8 MB, 294.68 kbit/s):

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2007-09-17 02:37:42
  Duration: 00:08:42.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 302 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 80 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-09-17 02:37:42
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 320x240, 173 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 5994 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-09-17 02:37:42
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 32 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-09-17 02:37:42
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 9 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-09-17 02:37:42
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
```

Any thoughts of what might be happening?

---

**UPDATE #1:**

It was suggested to use the HTML5 VIDEO tag, like so:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="file.mov" type="video/quicktime">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

To my surprise, this actually "worked" in Safari.  However, it broke horribly in other browsers that didn't support HTML5 as well as those that recognized this was not a supported video format.

**It has therefore been confirmed the VIDEO tag is not the solution**, as this breaks the backwards compatibility requirement.

**NEW INFORMATION:**

I have a confession. The `file.mov` shown above was done to simplify the example for readers.  The *actual* value is a URL containing a PHP script that selects which .MOV file to display.

I just discovered that when I use a file with `.mov`, rather than `.php`, the page works just fine. *This used to work as PHP ...for years.*

More disturbing, it *appears* that the plug-in is *not* looking at the `Content-Type` that's correctly being passed, but the file extension. This is either a bug on Apple's part, or a mistake on mine (and I hope that's the case). But at the moment, it's preventing me from serving dynamic content.

Apple's JavaScript function is generating the correct object/embed tags with my URL, and a static snapshot shows that if I use a file with the `.mov` extension it works, but not the script, even if both deliver identical content.

I'm doing further experiments to assert the Content-Type is coming across correctly. `wget` says it is, Safari's web inspector seems to saying otherwise.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Something strange is most certainly going on.

If I load `file.mov` in the browser directly, it plays.

If I load this `file.php` in the browser directly, it also plays.

```
<?php
  $filename = "file.mov";
  $handle = fopen( $filename, "rb" );
  if ( $handle ) {
    header( "Content-type: video/quicktime" ); 
    header( "Accept-Ranges: bytes" );
    header( "Content-Length: " . filesize( $filename ) );
    fpassthru( $handle );
    flush();
    exit;
  } // if handle
?>
```

If I load this `file.html` in the browser, interesting things happen.  The first entry shows a Missing Plug-In, the others play.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="320" height="256" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab#version=6,0,2,0" align="middle">
    <param name="src" value="file.php">
    <param name="kioskmode" value="true">
    <embed src="file.php" width="320" height="256" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" align="middle" kioskmode="true">
</object>

<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="320" height="256" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab#version=6,0,2,0" align="middle">
    <param name="src" value="file.mov">
    <param name="kioskmode" value="true">
    <embed src="file.mov" width="320" height="256" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" align="middle" kioskmode="true">
</object>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="file.php" type="video/quicktime">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="file.mov" type="video/quicktime">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This suggests, to me at least, that Apple *does* have a bug in that it will not load dynamic content.

Concur? Disagree? Thoughts?

I'm not *really* curious what the "right" way to do this is.

Another experiment, I changed the `video/quicktime` to `video/mp4` and it worked for the Safari version.

I fear I may have to detect if the browser is Safari, if it handles the VIDEO tag, and if so, emit that hack using the `.php` selection code instead of Apple's object/embed tags.

**UPDATE 3:**

Discovered that Safari is issuing this error message:

```
Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load
```

Found this interesting post in which [someone else confirms that videos from PHP don't work, but directly served they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042894/php-ipad-does-not-play-mp4-videos-delivered-by-php-but-if-accessed-directly-it).

This suggests videos should no longer be sent via [blob servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103103/failed-to-load-resource-plugin-handled-load-on-ios).

**SOLVED:**

That was the problem.  Where one used to be able to send the whole file, Safari and iOS don't like that anymore.

This is why delivering the same content behaved differently.  It was the delivery mechanism, not the content, that was the problem.

See the marked answer for working PHP code and credits.

Comment: dude, use the video tag. it's cross-browser compatible!

Comment: While, I appreciate the quick comments.  Several notes.  I made it pretty clear there was a reason I could _not_ switch to the VIDEO tag, in that I'm trying to maintain backwards compatibility and am using .MOV formats. I'll clarify that the link to the video tag shows only MP4, WebM, and Ogg are supported; not .MOV.  That said, Safari _does_ seem to allow the 'video/quicktime' type, but this does _not_ work in other browers.  As such, HTML5 VIDEO is confirmed as an unworkable solution.

Comment: you can convert your .mov files to other formats online. try online-convert.com

Comment: Interesting resource. But I have hundreds upon hundreds of .MOV files made over the course of a decade and a half. Some are quite sizable. These are a shared resource of a much larger system, where changing is bad and duplication is wasteful. I am less focused on the symptom of not playing a file, but on solving the root cause of why it used to work and has now stopped. Addressing _that_ fixes everything in one elegant move.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, except with small mp3s not working now in Safari 10. Does bring back that old IE feeling.

Answer (score 3):

This StackOverflow article got me to a working solution:

[Using php to output an mp4 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924061/using-php-to-output-an-mp4-video)

The problem is that Safari and iOS don't want the whole .MOV file delivered at once, and in fact, the plug-in will throw an error.  Rather it wants to chunk it up.

Here's the code that solved the problem, taken pretty much from the answer above and wrapped in a function:

```
function RenderVideo( $file ) {

  $fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');

  $size   = filesize($file); // File size
  $length = $size;           // Content length
  $start  = 0;               // Start byte
  $end    = $size - 1;       // End byte

  header('Content-type: video/mp4');
  header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

      $c_start = $start;
      $c_end   = $end;

      list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
      if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
          header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
          header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
          exit;
      }
      if ($range == '-') {
          $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
      }else{
          $range  = explode('-', $range);
          $c_start = $range[0];
          $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
      }
      $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
      if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
          header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
          header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
          exit;
      }
      $start  = $c_start;
      $end    = $c_end;
      $length = $end - $start + 1;
      fseek($fp, $start);
      header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
  }
  header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
  header("Content-Length: ".$length);


  $buffer = 1024 * 8;
  while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {

      if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
          $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
      }
      set_time_limit(0);
      echo fread($fp, $buffer);
      flush();
  }

  fclose($fp);
  exit();

}
```