# Can a slow Internet connection break PHP pseudo streaming? Or is it the code?

Tags: php, streaming

I am streaming mp4 files using this script https://stackoverflow.com/a/24076523/1066234 - It works actually for all devices that I have tested.

One of my users contacted me that he gets on Mac:

> The media could not be loaded, either the server or network failed or because the format is not supported

So I tested the streaming on Mac myself and it works. Besides direct embedding we also tried a js video player but nothing helped.

In the end the user told me that his internet connection is slow. So my basic question is:

Can a slow Internet connection break PHP pseudo streaming? Or is it something else in the code?

.

*PS: I am not sure if this question should be posted on stackoverflow I also thought of serverfault. If an admin can decide, please move the question appropriately.*

Comment: Is the user sure his 'internet connection' is slow?  What if he mean his computers is slow?  Have him run this to see how fast his internet connection is: http://www.speedtest.net/

Comment: what is the encoding of the MP4 ? though Mac OS X equipped with ability to decode most of the MP4 codecs, your MP4 might be using some codes that is unsupported.

Comment: Just wanted to add what confuses me even more: 1. The user says on Windows XP with the same internet connection, it works. 2. The user says that Youtube videos can be streamed without problem. (Okay, Youtube probably does not use pseudo streaming.)

Comment: @Raptor But why can I play the mp4 on my tested Mac? Safari and Chrome without problem.

Comment: Has the user run all of the Apple updates? (if that matters..)

Comment: Not all Macs have the same settings. Go try your link in Apple Store :)

Comment: @Chris Banks I tested on Mac OS X 10.9.5, Chrome 47.0, Safari 9.0.2, plus iPhone 4 - streaming worked. The user tested on "Mac OS X 10.5, 10.6, 10.9, iPad and iPhone (iOS 5, 6, 8)" - nothing worked, he said. That is why I think it must be the internet connection and this leads to my question :)

Comment: Try the network throttling function in Google Chome.  You can find it here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

Comment: @AgeDeO Great idea, I did so. Setting "3G 750KB/s 100ms RTT" the video streamed just fine at my computer (Windows 7 currently). Even with "2G 250 KB/s 300ms RTT" it worked. Could it be that the Mac reacts differently?