# HTML5 video in Safari only working locally

Tags: html, video, safari

I have an mp4 video in my site. If I run it in `localhost` using Safari it works. But if I check it in production (Safari) is not working. The same if I go to the full path of the video.

This is my code:

```
<video loop="loop" muted="muted" poster="/videos/dashboards_poster.png" autoplay="autoplay" src="videos/dashboards.mp4"></video>
```

Also, if I go to: https://example.com/videos/dashboards.mp4 is not working and in the console I'm seeing:

`Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load`

But if go to: http://localhost:9000/videos/dashboards.mp4 is working!

This is only happening in Safari. Chrome and Firefox works fine. My Safari version is: 9.1 (11601.5.17.1)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this problem only on safari, or have you tried other browsers? It could be a safari quirk or a universal problem.

Also, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042894/php-ipad-does-not-play-mp4-videos-delivered-by-php-but-if-accessed-directly-it

Comment: @kirkpatt only Safari. But locally it works

Comment: I suppose all I can say is to make sure your permissions allow for the production version to access the video. Otherwise, I don't have many other ideas. Hope that helps, and good luck.

Comment: @MatiTucci Ever find a solution??

Comment: Did you find anything so far? I'm exeriencing similar problems, my App streams perfectly when run locally but fails (Safari only) when streamed from our staging server. I believe this might have to do with https vs http and maybe there's issues with certificate authorities (using let's encrypt).